# Flask - are my endpoints visible to users

Tags: python, security, flask

For security reasons, I want to know whether all of my endpoint addresses can be accessed by anyone with access to the (home) address and port numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running your application on a server or PC that can be accessed from the internet, and the port it is running on is opened - as opposed to running locally on your local network/PC - then yes, any client that knows (or guesses) your IP and the port on which the application is running can attempt to access any endpoint in your application.

Note that although the client will not have a full list of endpoints that can be accessed, a common attack vector is to repeatedly attempt to guess endpoints - for example `/admin` or `/debug`. Due to automation, it is practically guaranteed that if your server running the flask application is open to the internet, requests will be made to try to access endpoints by third-parties.

Due to this, it is essential to lock down any sensitive information behind security, be that IP white-listing, or by login mechanisms such as those provided by the [`flask-login`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module.